# react-draft-wysiwyg set editor state with createWithContent() not showing anything in editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

experiencing problem in setting initial editor state , using createWithContent()

The "richTextDescription" is what stored in database as

```
 {"blocks":[{"key":"cipnj","text":"Admore ","type":"header-one","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":7,"style":"BOLD"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"3ncop","text":"jhdf","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":4,"style":"color-rgb(44,130,201)"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"2ra8a","text":"no please work !!","type":"header-five","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":17,"style":"color-rgb(44,130,201)"},{"offset":0,"length":17,"style":"BOLD"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}
```

setting initial use state hook:

```
 const [richTextDescription, setRichTextDescription] = useState(
            content.richTextDescription
          );
```

the state change method:

```
  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
        setEditorState(editorState);
        setRichTextDescription(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
      };
```

here setting the editor state with createWithContent().

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
      convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(richTextDescription))
    ),
  });



<Editor
initialEditorState={editorState}
onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
}}
/>
```

the following shows output fine

```
<div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: draftToHtml(JSON.parse(richTextDescription)),
    }}
 ></div>
```

but the intial editor state which should show the editable text within editor is now showing. it shows blank

Comment: try to remove 'editorState:` level?